# sqlite and python filter results

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python function to do query from sqlite. as the following:

```
def Query(X, Y, Z):
```

where X, Y & Z are the columns of the database.
so for example when

```
Query(1, 2, 3)
```

it will go to the sqlite as follows:

```
<code>SELECT OUTPUT FROM IMAGES WHERE (X=?) AND (Y=?) AND (Z=?)",[X,Y,Y]</code>
```

So, it will take numbers 1,2 & 3 and will fetch them from sqlite.
The problem I have when the input of:

```
Query(X, Y, Z)
```

has one or more empty fields, as example:

```
Query(1, 2, '')
```

in this case I want the database to ignore column Z, but I can not figure out how to do it.
I have tried

```
SELECT OUTPUT FROM IMAGES WHERE (X=? OR X) AND (Y=? OR Y) AND (Z=? OR Z)",[X,Y,Z]
```

but this statement is not working well.

Could someone help, how to ignore a column if the input from Python is empty.

Comment: Why not use if statements to run different queries? It's a bit longer, but it's still a good solution.

Comment: I could use if statement but I would like ti minimize the code. Moreover I have tried something similar to this statement in PHP, and it was working fine, So this was this first solution to pop in my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be something wrong with the testing of an empty string. You could try something similar to the following:

```
"SELECT OUTPUT FROM IMAGES WHERE (X=? OR ?='') AND (Y=? OR ?='') AND (Z=? OR ?='')",[X,Y,Z]
```

But admittedly it is more like a hint than an actual verified solution.

**Edit**

Probably you need named parameters:

```
def Query(X, Y, Z):
    import sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT OUTPUT FROM IMAGES WHERE (X=:px OR :px='') AND (Y=:py OR :py='') AND (Z=:pz OR :pz='')", {"px": X, "py": Y, "pz": Z})
```

**Edit**

Try this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1a462/1).

**Edit**

Consider the following fragment of your query:

```
(Y=? OR Y)
```

For a database row for which Y='foo', it is equivalent to:

```
('foo'=? OR 'foo')
```

Since 'foo' converts to false, that is equivalent to:

```
('foo'=? OR false)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
('foo'=?)
```

Which can be true only if you queried for Y='foo'. If instead you queried Y='', you get:

```
('foo'='')
```

Which is obviously false.

Hence your query is really behaving like the original one, the one without ORs.

Comment: I did the testing when all inputs are provided it was working good. and also if the last input Z is not provided it is working fine. But when X or Y are not provided it does not fetch anything. sounds weird.

Comment: Sounds weird indeed, because the query is symmetric and X, Y and Z should behave in the same way. Try to play a little bit with the sqlfiddle I posted, I think you have always been quite near to the solution. In my case (WebSQL on sqlfiddle) most strings appear to be converted to false, hence when substituted in the **or** clause, don't help in making the group in parenthesis true.

Comment: The named parameters worked pretty well. thanks for the clever answer.